# PyCharm project directory of images not accessible in code

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, file-not-found

I created a PyCharm python project that has a directory of images. When I try to access one of the files in the directory, PyCharm gives me a "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

The icon of the image directory folder in the PyCharm project has a circle in it, which I think suggests that PyCharm thinks it is a package.

Either, how do I change the directory from being a package to a regular directory, or, am I missing something else about having a directory under a project in PyCharm?

The code I'm using is simply:

```
f = open("images/image.png", "r")
```

Here is a screengrab of the folder icon with a circle in it.
[Folder icon in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIEzu.png)

Comment: please could you add the code you are using to load the image ?

Comment: @PRMoureu I've added the code I'm using to open the file

Comment: if you've double-checked the spelling, add `import os;(print(os.getcwd()))` in the file to check if the image directory is in the same folder

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've tried that and it is all as it should be. Any idea why the folder icon has the circle in it, rather than being a regular folder directory?

Comment: all my images folders have this icon, not sure why Pycharm choose it, but it's not related to your issue. You may try to specify the full path

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that. I couldn't get over why the folder was represented in that way when I wasn't doing anything to set it as a package or special folder.

Comment: So, I kept adding new directories to the project with names like resources, assets etc. They all are created with the folder icon with the circle in it, even before I have put any images in them. I created one directory named '64 x 90'. This directory did not have a circle in the icon, and, I can read files from the directory without an error. I have no idea why.

Comment: as the name begin with numbers, it cannot be a python package, that's why the icon is normal... but for the working part : very weird. Is this the same image you've tried in a different folder ?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely the same image file just copied from the folder it could not be read from to the new folder named 64 x 90.